# What is the expected format of HTTP Accept-Language locale string?

Tags: http, http-headers, internationalization, http2

On Mac OS Chrome browser (v87), when I make an HTTP request, I observe an Accept-Language header as follows:

```
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,es;q=0.8,es-MX;q=0.7
```

On Mac OS Safari browser (v13.1.3), when I make the same HTTP request, I observe Accept-Language header as follows:

```
Accept-Language: en-us
```

My question is, are both of the above formats correct?  The variance between uppercase 'en-US' and lowercase 'en-us' has actually led to a bug in some routing code.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, both examples you provided conform to the specified syntax for the `Accept-Language` header.

That syntax is spelled out [explicitly](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-5.3.5) in RFC 7231. Put simply, the value is a comma-separated list of language tags, where each tag is optionally followed by a semicolon and a weight (`;q=...`) indicating the desirability of the language.

The [specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4647#section-2) is explicit that comparisons must be done in a case-insensitive manner, so any "routing code" that produces different behavior depending on case is not conformant with the HTTP specification.

> Language tags and thus language ranges are to be treated as case-insensitive: there exist conventions for the capitalization of some
> of the subtags, but these MUST NOT be taken to carry meaning.
> Matching of language tags to language ranges MUST be done in a case-insensitive manner.

Answer (score 0):

As a followup to this question. The lowercase locale string may be valid according to HTTP.  But it has been confirmed as a bug in WebKit.

Source:
https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=163096

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. To clarify, the bug isn't about the HTTP header, it's about the DOM API. Specifically, the value of `window.navigator.language` must use the uppercase country code.